# Gitlab CI .gitlab-ci.yml reference syntax for linux:build: syntax

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

The majority of .gitlab-ci.yml files which I have seen follow the pattern

```
build-code:
  stage: build
  script:
    do-somthing.
```

However, I see some documentation that has steps defined like this

```
build:default:
  stage: build
  script:
    do-something.
```

I do not understand why some steps are written with [a-z]+:[a-z]+: pattern as demonstrated by this [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) for "needs"

Can someone explain which concept is being used when we write steps in this pattern "linux:build:" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the pattern `build:linux:` if you have other types of builds in your pipeline, like `build:mac:` and `build:netbsd`.
But if you prefer you can write `build-linux:`, ... instead.

It is just a question of style. No other means. And of course, it's not related to builds. In general it's used when you want to visually group similar jobs: `group:action1`, ...